# Getting dates associated to acct sa output stats

Tags: user-management, statistics

I'm trying to get stats on global CPU usage of a server on a per-user basis so I installed [GNU Accounting](https://www.gnu.org/software/acct/manual/accounting.html) (acct) (on Ubuntu server 16.04).

When asking for stats with `sa -m`, it takes data from the current `/var/log/account/pacct`, which is rotated by the acct service. I understood that I can give the archived rotated files as input to it, if I want to get statistics on older entries.

The problem is that `sa` gives no dates on the statistics that are displayed, and I couldn't find a way to have dates on it? This would allow me get statistics on a day or week manner.

Comment: Are you looking for something within `sa` command or `ac` command too? `ac -d` will gives you daily report but only for login logout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that on Ubuntu the `acct` service is logrotated each day. This gives the option to run `sa -m` on each archived log file, in `/var/log/account`, to have a per-day report, which is sufficient for my use.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like :

`dump-acct /var/log/account/pacct`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't allow to specify any date range